# Adding new lines until getting a specific number line python

Tags: python, file

I have large number of files with different line numbers and same column numbers(17 columns) in a directory. I want to loop through all the files and perform the following operation.

1. If number of lines in file is smaller than 100
2. Add new lines with value(0.00 0.00 ...) with same column number (17) until file has 100 lines
3. If line number between 100 and 200, then repeat step 2 but upto 200 lines

the code below but I don't know what I have to write in the if statements to get actual results

```
 os.chdir('./directory/') 
 names={}
 for fn in glob.glob('*.dat'):
 with open(fn) as f:
 names[fn]=sum(1 for line in f)
 if names[fn] < 100:
  .....
 if names[fn]>100 and names[fn]<200:
  ....
```

thanks.

Comment: you want to edit and add lines of data to `.dat` files? have you tested that you can open, read and edit the `.dat` files? if so then [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) might be used to count the line numbers in the `.dat` files.

Comment: yes I want to edit and add  lines of data to .dat files. I can open read and count number of lines with code. After counting lines I cannot add lines to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care for a bash implemented solution, you can look into this `bash` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printfn() {
    for (( i=0;i<$1;i++ ))
        do
            for (( j=0;j<$3;j++ ))
            do
               printf "0.00  "#<---change spacing that fits your column requiments 
            done
            printf "\n"
        done >> $2
    }

#Here columns are 17
COLS=17                       #<---change column numbers if you need
f=(*.dat)
for file in ${f[@]}; do
    lines=`cat $file | wc -l`
    if [[ $lines -lt 100 ]] ; then 
        printfn 100-$lines $file 17
    elif [[ $lines -lt 200 && $lines -gt 100 ]]; then
        printfn 200-$lines $file 17
    fi
done
```

This fills up the file with zeros if #of lines is less than 100 or the number of lines is in between 200 and 100. Put this into a file ( say script.sh ).

Don't forget to `chmod +x script.sh` this